# fontspec error: "font-not-found" inconsolata RedHat

Tags: fonts, xetex, inconsolata

I am using RStudio Server on a RedHat 7.3 machine. I keep getting a fontspec error that the font inconsolata cannot be found. I'm not very familiar with linux, and very new to RedHat. The same script works on my Mac, so I think I am missing a package. I have not found what font collection includes inconsolata.

Comment: the font is freely available see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconsolata you won't need any tex package just install that font in your system (or in fact just put it in the same directory as the document)

Comment: Thansks, @DavidCarlisle. I added the OTF file to the same directory, but it's not picking up. Is there another step?

Comment: if it's in the same directory and you specify it by filename including extension `\setmainfont{whateveritscalled.otf}`  it should work, usually, on a good day.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, it seems to work when I compile the intermediate tex file that RStudio generates, but the RStudio pdf does not use the right font. I'll keep exploring. While I do this, I wonder if you know if there is a inconsolata package for RedHat?

Comment: if r studio (which i don't have)  does lualatex /path/to/file  rather than cd /path/to; lualatex file then the font would need to be in the working directory not the directory with the tex file (which is why it's better to install the font really but I'm out of practice with linux font setup:-)

Comment: You can search for packages. Probably with `yum` as I don't suppose RedHat has `dnf` yet. Many Linux distros package Inconsolata. I don't know specifically about RH.